# Why The do_upload is not working, and showing the error image is not selected?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

This is my**View**  along codes.

```
 <?=form_open_multipart('test/uploadimage/add_image',['class'=>'']);?>
<?=form_upload(['name'=>'img1','class'=>'form-control']); ?>
 <?=form_input(['name'=>'add','type'=>'submit','value'=>'Add']);?>
<?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error?>
 <?=form_close(); ?>
```

This is my **Controller** in which I want to upload the image in add_image function.

```
<?php
  class  Uploadimage extends MY_Controller{
  function index(){
    $this->load->view('test/upload_image');
       }
 function  add_image(){
    $config=[
             'upload_path'=>'./uploads',
             'allowed_types'=>'png|gif|jpg',

          ];
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload()){
        echo 'succee';
    }
   else {
        echo 'failled';
        $upload_error= $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('test/upload_image',compact('upload_error'));
      }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Showing this **error**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line in your code.

```
$this->upload->do_upload();
```

with

```
$this->upload->do_upload('img1');
```

Comment: I tried.. $img=$this->input->post('img1');
$this->upload->do_upload($img);
but didn't success.

Comment: Thanks...........it works..................Can I rate your profile and how? because I m new user of this platform.